# Software for creating complex schematics involving organs and circuitry

Tags: linux, drawing, vector-graphics

I am looking for a Linux-based software that is best suited for creating these types of schematics, involving electric-style circuits and organisms / individual organs.

[image: Schematic electric-style example]

I will have separate vector-based graphics for anatomic components (like human body, arm, for example) as `.svg` files which I would like to import and incorporate in the schematics similar to above. The end product should be vector-based.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/). If you turn on the grid<sup>1</sup> and hide page borders<sup>2</sup> you get an infinite canvas with snapping<sup>3</sup>.
(You can also save this as your default template.)

Here is an example I made for a circuit:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> Toggle grid: <kbd>#</kbd>.

<sup>2</sup> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, uncheck `Show page border`.

<sup>3</sup> Toggle snapping: <kbd>%</kbd>.

Comment: Where did you get the symbols from? Did you draw them all manually?

Comment: Yes, I drew them. At that time I had to draw a lot of circuits and just drawing the symbols I needed was faster for me than finding a free icon pack which contained all of them.

Answer (score 2):

While a general purpose vector editor like Inkscape would be fine for creating simple diagrams, you might be more interested in a tool more specialised for creating diagrams like [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.en).

- Runs on Linux
- Free and Open source
- Import custom shapes
- Export to SVG